# attempt to access beyond end of device LINUX

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to copy a file system from SD card to another drive and receive this messages. 
I did this before and was working just fine. I am stuck as trying to figure it out for a couple of days, any ideas??

Many thx

```
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/crypto/
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/crypto/tcrypt.ko
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/autofs4/
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/autofs4/autofs4.ko
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/nls/
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/nls/nls_utf8.ko
lib/modules/3.0.35-4.1.0+qmx6+gbb1b8ca/kernel/fs/nls/nls_ascii.ko
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=17943558856, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=16130791936, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=1918282448, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=3994644768, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=11746206792, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=4035384840, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=16238641536, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=501451168, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=12227999984, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=23780166832, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=17943558856, limit=15255782
cp: read error: Input/output error
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=2147487752, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=2147487752, limit=15255782
cp: read error: Input/output erroEXT3-fs error (device mmcblk0p1): htree_dirblock_to                       _tree: bad entry in directory #429131: directory entry across blocks - offset=0, ino                       de=2019488269, rec_len=19580, name_len=34
r
cp: can't stat 'dcb/opt/datik/www/js/menu.js': Input/output error
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=47814352, limit=15255782
attempt to access beyond end of device
mmcblk0p1: rw=0, want=47814352, limit=15255782
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I guess the problem isn't with a code (it is just `cp` command or similar), but with the file system's content, which is corrupted. Or with a driver, which incorrectly interprets it. So the question isn't a *programming* one, and thus **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.